# Problem with {tidyr} spread function dropping rows

Tags: r, tidyr

When trying to create dummy variables there is an issue where a row is being merged for some reason. This results in a row being associated with two groups, hence not a dummy variable. The following code reproduces the issue.

```
df = data.frame(group = c(4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), time = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4), age = c(65, 86, 49, 71, 71, 76), year = c(72, 74, 72, 76, 76, 77), death = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

df %>% mutate(i=1) %>% spread(group, i, fill=0)
```

You can see after running the code that there is a row that is merged resulting in a subject that is in two groups at once. Is this an error with the code or an error with the function?

Comment: `spread` has been deprecated, use `pivot_wider`. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a column with `row_number()` because there are some duplicate rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(i=1, rn = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(group, i, fill=0) %>%
    select(-rn)
```

---

Or using `pivot_wider`

```
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number(), i = 1) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = i, values_fill = list(i = 0))
```

Comment: Ah I see the issue now. Thank you very much for your time. I will accept this answer in 9 minutes.